# Wordpress admin panel login issue on Amazon lightsail instance

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

i have installed wordpress on Amazon lightsail. I followed the steps which is mentioned in this guide - https://jiocare.net/install-wordpress-amazon-lightsail-instance/ I got the wordpress password from SSH terminal as it has mentioned. Default username for wordpress is "user" as i noted. But i can't login to the wordpress. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Could you please expand upon "I can't login"? Did you get to the login screen? What was the error message?

Comment: I followed those instructions and successfully logged into my server.

Comment: It gives a wrong credentials error as normally appear when entering wrong credentials in wordpress.

Comment: Well, it works for me! Perhaps delete that server and launch a new one, try again?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, now it is working. Thanks!!

Comment: And i like to ask another question here, if it is that okay? I installed mautic plugin for wordpress. But it is not showing the analytics for me. Any ideas. I added ip address of lightsail+path to the plugins installation in wordpress.

Comment: That looks like a different topic. Please ask it as a new Question.

Comment: Okay, no worries